# Can I use Bootstrap 5 with Vue v2 and Bootstrap-vue Components?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, vue-component, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-vue

The project that I work on is created with Nuxt v2 (Vue v2, Bootstrap v4, Bootstrap-vue). The project uses bootstrap-vue components like:

```
  <b-navbar toggleable="md" type="dark" :sticky="true">
    <b-navbar-brand>...</b-navbar-brand>
    <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
      <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">...</b-nav-item-dropdown>

        <b-nav-item-dropdown right>
          ...
          <b-dropdown-item>...</b-dropdown-item>
        </b-nav-item-dropdown>
      </b-navbar-nav>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-navbar>
```

I want to migrate to Bootstrap v5. So, my question is can I keep using bootstrap-vue components with Bootstrap 5? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can*, but since class names have changed between Bootstrap 4 and 5, some components will be adding the wrong classes giving broken styling.

So I wouldn't recommend it.